# Microsoft Graph API Get token without user sign-in

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, token

I would like to have access to my OneDrive files using Microsoft Graph API in Java. I've tested this sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java, and added a "getFiles" part to it which displays informations about my files. For the moment, this works perfectly.

But I would like to avoid user sign-in each time I run the sample. Indeed, in the authentication part of the code, a DeviceCode is used to acquire the token, and I'm redirected to a Microsoft web page where I sign-in and authorize the application to have access to my account.

I tried to replace the DeviceCode with IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationParameters (I got this from here : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/blob/master/Integrated-Windows-Auth-Flow/src/main/java/IntegratedWindowsAuthFlow.java (line 73)) using my scopes and email address as parameters, but I got the error below :

"com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: WsTrust endpoint not found in metadata document"

**Edit : IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationParameters isn't suitable for personal accounts like mine (xxxxx@hotmail.com), is there another way to acquire token with this type of account ?**

Is it the right solution to access personal accounts ? Or did I miss something in the App configuration in AAD ? Are there any other solutions ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a global tenant administrator account, which is your `.onmicrosoft.com` account.

Please verify and make sure you have logged in with the proper account for the App you registered.

```
username = xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

[image]

***Update***

Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) supports federated users only - users created in Active Directory and backed by Azure AD. Users created directly in Azure AD without Active Directory backing (managed users) can't use this authentication flow.

Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#constraints-2).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a "onmicrosoft.com" but "hotmail.com", is there a solution for this type of account ?

Comment: @digimip09 I'm sorry, but that's not going to happen.The answer has been updated:).

Comment: thank you for your help :) I edited my post in case other ideas come up